# count files in a linux directory and store the result in a ODI variable

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I need to count files in a linux directory and store the result in an ODI variable.

I tried creating a procedure using OdiOSCommand and command as under

```
#count = ls  /export/home/abc/Testing |wc -l
```

The above procedure is executing without errors but no data is getting stored in the ODI variable.

Can someone please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ODI but you should [avoid parsing `ls` output.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)